# In shell-script, how to compare two files and know which one is latest?

Tags: linux, shell

I have two folders A & B. A is my working directory and B is my backup folder.

I compare files in the two folders and backup (From A to B) if there are any changes in A.

So, I used:

```
diffResult=( diff -q "${A/file-nmae}" "${B/file-name}" )

if [ -n "${diffResult}" ]; then

    <code to copy>
else

    <something else>
fi
```

The only problem is, in some cases, file in B is latest than A. So I dont want to backup in this case. How do I do it and how to check if which file is newer?

Comment: Use `stat %Y filename` to get the modification time, and compare them.

Comment: Or use the `-nt` comparison operator.

Comment: Isn't there a `$` missing – should be `diffResult=$( ...`, no?

Comment: while this is OK as question, but - just IMHO - you should learn `git`. Doing `diff` and checking the times and copy - is doable, but some version control is probably more error proof and also has more features... also, the `rsync` could help...

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use the if primary expression `-nt` ie

```
if [ "A/fileX" -nt "B/fileX" ]
then
  mv A/fileX B/fileX
done
```

The [[ documentation ]](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) says :

> [ FILE1 -nt FILE2 ]  True if FILE1 has been changed more recently than
>   FILE2, or if FILE1 exists and FILE2 does not.

Comment: I'd go ahead and quote the filenames when using `test` (e.g. `[]`) to avoid the error if either `"A/fileX"` or `"B/fileX"` have been moved or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> To find differents  in  b.txt

```
fgrep -v -f a.txt b.txt
```

> To find differents in a.txt

```
fgrep -v -f b.txt a.txt
```

> To find last modified ,last modified file at end

```
ls -lrt
```

> To find both changes and last modified use

```
fgrep -v -f a b && ls -lrt a b  | tail -1
```

Comment: I already know the difference, I want to know which one is the latest

Comment: Try this   fgrep -v -f a b && ls -lrt a b  | tail -1